# como coloco un id personalizado al helper form_start

Tags: symfony2, twig

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Symfony 2.6 y necesito colocarle el valor del **id** al helper `form_start`, el cuál solo me muestra predeterminado el atributo **nombre**.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [referencia oficial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) form_start renderiza el tag de inicio de un formulario y el prototipo de form_start es el siguiente:

> form_start(view, variables)

Por lo tanto en **variables** puedes pasarle la variable **attr** la cual te permite incorporar atributos al tag en concreto.

Quedaría algo así:

```
{{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'id': 'tu_id'}}) }}
```